# ByteBuffer.getShort(index) not returning expected bit value

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, bytecode, bytebuffer

I am trying to get data from an mp3 header(header starting from index 32), using ByteBuffer,
So when I use the getInt() method which returns the total 32bits of an mp3 header(Mp3 Header is of 32 bits).

```
int bitRate = 0;
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(header);
int frame_header = 0;
int size = buf.position(9).getInt();//size=22;
frame_header = 10 + size; //frameHeader=32;
int b = buf.getInt(frame_header);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b)); // 11111111111110111011010001000000
short a = buf.getShort(frame_header); 
short aa = buf.getShort(48);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Short.toUnsignedInt(a))); // 1111111111111011 expected the starting 16 bits of header
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Short.toUnsignedInt(aa))); //100101110000 wrong value expected should be the next 16 bit of the header which is 1011010001000000
```

what seems to be the problem?

FYI- I know we have a library but I want to use this method to get the bitrate.

Comment: Have you considered that ByteBuffer is Big Endian by default?

Comment: Where does `48` come from? Should `buf.getShort(48)` be `buf.getShort(frame_header + 2)`?

Comment: Yes, it is considered it Big Endian.@harold.

Comment: actually, in mp3 bitrate start from headerIndex+16, so in my case, it is 32+16. and using frame_header+2, does help it returns 1011010001000000.